# Is this a linked list?

Tags: c, struct, linked-list

I just did this code and its so difficult to check if the **list** is **linked** as it should. Is it possible to see if I have **linked** the **list** correctly?

.h file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct talstrul
{
    int num;
    struct talstrul *next;


};
```

.c file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "clabb2head.h"

void main()
{   typedef struct talstrul talstrul;
    int vek[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    talstrul *pek1=NULL;
    int langd = sizeof(vek)/sizeof(vek[0]);

    int i;
    for(i=0; i<langd; i++)
    {
        talstrul obj1;
        obj1.num = vek[i];
        obj1.next = pek1;
        pek1 = &obj1;

    }

    printf("%d",*pek1);
}
```

I know atleast that pek1 Points to the value 5 so something is correct atleast :)

What if I change the main program to:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "clabb2head.h"

void main()
{   typedef struct talstrul talstrul;
    int vek[] = {1,2,3,4,5,9};
    talstrul *pek1=NULL;
    int langd = sizeof(vek)/sizeof(vek[0]);

    int i;
    for(i=0; i<langd; i++)
    {
        talstrul *obj1 = malloc(sizeof(talstrul));
        obj1->num = vek[i];
        obj1->next = pek1;
        pek1 = obj1;

    }

    printf("%d",*pek1);
}
```

Should the list be saved now?

Comment: Yes it is : ) But I would not recommend you to make a linked list that complicated

Comment: `talstrul obj1;` is a local object, and will be used on each iteration of the loop. After the loop it will be out of scope, with pek1 still pointing to it.

Comment: No... you end up with `pek1` pointing to a `talstrul` that is no longer valid as `obj1` was was local to the for loop... and the results from the earlier iterations aren't kept anyway.

Comment: but why does it then print the value 5 when the code reaches the printline?? Dmitri

Comment: Because your struct is composed of the number, then the pointer. At the end, pek1 has your final struct loaded into it. Printing it as an integer, the first 4 bytes are read, which correspond to the integer. So all it's doing is saying "The last thing that you stored in me, the first 4 bytes are this number". It's a coincidence.

Comment: Because nothing overwrote that part of the stack before you printed it.

Comment: Try adding `talstrul obj2; obj2.num = 26;` between your for loop and your printf... depending on your compiler, etc. it might not print 5 anymore.

Comment: Minor issue: Use `int vek[] = {1,2,3,4,5};` vs. `int vek[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};`.

Comment: actually loosers, it is a linked list despite what you say!! Tested it right now, I get all the values as I walk the link backwards :D

Comment: Your revised code works (inserting at the beginning of the list each time), but you should use `pek1->num` instead of `*pek1` in your printf, and you should free the list at the end (when you're done with it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand how structs get allocated and deallocated, your "talstrul" items are being built on the stack and then destroyed at the end of it. You need to allocate them using `malloc` (and, of course, free it up using `free` at the end) and then assign the resulting pointer to your "next" value.

Also, you need to keep track of where your "head" object is. Every object points forward, not backwards, which means that at the end, you have a pointer to the last object, but no way of finding where the first object is.